# Office Online Server integrate with Exchange 2013

Tags: 2016, office-web-apps

Hi I have sharepoint 2016 Intranet farm and Exchange 2013 , here i want to install Office online server for sharepoint 2016 and can i also want to integrate with Exchange and in our org we have exchange 2013 and we want to use for open attachments in exchange web app

here i can i integrate office online server with exchange 2013 is it supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you mix up the terms "Office Web Apps" and "Office Online Server". So it is not absolutely clear what you want to set up. I assume that you want to set up OfficeOnline Server and not Office Web Apps.

**Term definition:**

"Office Web Apps Server" is the product for the 2013 product family. It has been renamed in it's 2016 version to "Office Online Server"

**Answer:**

[This blog](https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2016/05/04/office-online-server-now-available/) says, it works in "some scenarios". The [Office Online Server version compatibility list](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/office-online-server) says "Not supported". You shouldn't set this up in production.

My recommendation: Set up OfficeWebApps2013 for Exchange2013 and OfficeOnlineServer2016 for SharePoint 2016. You don't have to spend extra money on licenses and the hardware-footprint for those two servers is relative small.